# Email not being sent in an onEdit function google sheet script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to do two things once a checkbox is marked

1. pass the row onto a different sheet (which works)
2. send an email to a recipient (which does not work)

I put a gui message to see where the code fails and it runs perfectly up until the send email function.

I tried an onEdit installable trigger, but that makes the script runs twice, but also, without sending the email.

Any thoughts?

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;
  if (src.getName() != "Open Assignments" || r.columnStart != 10 || r.rowStart == 1) return;
  const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Completed Assignments ");
  dest.insertRows(3, 1);
  src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,10).moveTo(dest.getRange(3,1,1,10));
  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var emailAddress = dest.getRange(3,5).getValue();
  var subject = 'Your design is ready!'
  var message = dest.getRange(3,9).getValue();
  ui.alert(subject);
  MailApp.SendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

Comment: Quote the error message received.

Comment: I think your best best is to follow doubleunary's suggestions and change the name of the function so it won't operate on simple triggers and set up an installable trigger.

Answer (score 1):

```
function test(){
  MailApp.SendEmail("yourself@gmail.com", "Test", "test");
}
```

Just run the above function and authenticate your script. Only then onedit will send email. Onedit is not allowed to send email without authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine, but you will have to rename the `onEdit` function to something like `sendEmailOnEdit` to avoid triggers firing twice — if you fail to do that, the [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) will still be active even when you have already set an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

The email will get sent from the account who installed the trigger.

Use `console.log()` instead of `Ui.alert()` to make debugging easier.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. It seems to be working now. The fixes were:

1. As @doubleunary suggested, I changed the function name to SendEmailOnEdit (it only works when I put the 'S' of 'Send' in caps for some reason.
2. Used an installable trigger
3. Changed the MailApp.sendEmail to **G**mailApp.sendEmail

Here is the revised code (minus the debugging):

```js
function SendEmailonEdit(e) {
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;
  if (src.getName() != "Open Assignments" || r.columnStart != 10 || r.rowStart == 1) return;
  const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Completed Assignments ");
  dest.insertRows(3, 1);
  src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,10).moveTo(dest.getRange(3,1,1,10));
  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
  //var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var emailAddress = dest.getRange(3,5).getValue();
  var subject = 'Your design is ready!'
  var message = dest.getRange(3,9).getValue();
  //gui.alert(subject);
  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,subject,message);
}
```